# Type error:Cannot read property of undefined error generated in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Type error:Cannot read property of undefined error generated in browser [console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUUKI.png)..I am trying to save the form with any information and it generates this error in the console.If i enter all the details and save the form then there's no error generated..as a newbie i was not able to trace where it's going wrong.below is the html and controller.Can some one help me to trace the bug..

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('userSaveMunitOperatorCtrl', userSaveMunitOperatorCtrl);

    userSaveMunitOperatorCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope','ngDialog', 'userSvc'];

    function userSaveMunitOperatorCtrl($scope, $rootScope,ngDialog, userSvc) {
        $scope.name = 'userSaveMunitOperatorCtrl';

        $scope.regularExpression = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
        $scope.onSaveChanges = function (options) {
            $scope.errorMessage = '';
            $scope.saveMunitOperatorForm.$setPristine();
            if ($scope.user.mUnitPassword && $scope.user.mUnitPasswordConfirm) {
                if ($scope.user.mUnitPassword === $scope.user.mUnitPasswordConfirm) $scope.saveMunitOperatorForm.$setValidity("confirm", true);
                else $scope.saveMunitOperatorForm.$setValidity("confirm", false);
            }
            if ($scope.saveMunitOperatorForm.$valid) {
                var mUnitData = { userId: '', mUnitOperatorName: '', mUnitPassword: '' };

                mUnitData.userId = $rootScope.currentUser.id;
                mUnitData.mUnitOperatorName = $scope.user.mUnitOperatorName;
                mUnitData.mUnitPassword = $scope.user.mUnitPassword;

                userSvc.saveMUnitOperator(mUnitData).then(function (response) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("SaveMunitOperator", response);
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("refresh_MUnit", { dataItem: JSON.stringify(mUnitData.mUnitOperatorName) });

                    if ($scope.closeThisDialog)
                        $scope.closeThisDialog('confirm');

                    ngDialog.openConfirm({
                        template: 'messageDialogId',
                        className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
                        data: {
                            'message': $rootScope.$translate.instant("Maintenance unit info saved successfully.")
                        }
                    });
                },
                    function (error) {
                    if (error) {
                        if (error.message.indexOf(':') >= 0) {
                            var errorMessage = error.message.split(':');
                            $scope.errorMessage = errorMessage[1];
                        }
                        else {
                            $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        };

     };


})();
```

```html
<div class="row pt bd1-top">
            <button type="submit" ng-click="onSaveChanges()" class="btn btn-labeled btn-green mr pull-right" data-qaid="munit-text-savemu-save">
                <span class="btn-label">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                </span>{{'Save Changes' | translate}}
            </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare `$scope.user` first before use it as a model

Like this

```
$scope.user = {};
```

Comment: where should i declare it exactly?

Comment: at the beginning of the controller  below or above of `$scope.name` @Atchu

Comment: Thanks @ Anik Islam Abhi